# Why doesn't the coordinates update properly?

Tags: android, touch

I want to make a circle move on the screen, and follow my touch. It works fine, but I want to set a range to move in. My problem is, that if I reach the distance 100, the coordinates doesn't update. Or looks like it doesn't update, my circle freeze on the screen.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bp5vmz1qln25amc/distance_problem.java

Comment: `if(distance > 100) //hatótáv beállítása 
                { 
                    mPosX = Last_mPosX; 
                    mPosY = Last_mPosY; 
                } 
                Last_mPosX = mPosX; 
                Last_mPosY = mPosY; ` 

In here are you sure Last_mPosX and Last_mPosY is not null or empty ?

Comment: It should be the last correct position, isn't it?

Comment: I mean you have to learn Last_mPosX and Last_mPosY is not empty. Please try to write it to LOG screen with `Log.i("VALUE",Last_mPosX+" - "+Last_mPosY); ` and see results

Comment: Well, it isn't empty :)

Comment: it should about View class but don't know exactly what to do.